# Need Help Generating LP Contract Addresses using Uniswap V3 SDK

Tags: uniswap, polygon, uniswapv3, typescript, npm

I'm in a bit of a coding jam, and could use some help understanding how to utilize the Uniswap V3 SDK to **generate accurate Liquidity Pool Addresses**. I have already gone through the uniswap documentation and other stack exchange questions, and have determined that I would benefit from direct assistance.

This code is generated with large influence from [the official Uniswap V3 SDK mint-position example](https://github.com/Uniswap/examples/blob/main/v3-sdk/minting-position/src/libs/pool.ts#L24-L29), so I am very confused as to why this method is not correctly generating pool addresses.

For this example, I will attempt to generate the address for the [CRV-MATIC Uniswap 0.3% Liquidity Pool](https://info.uniswap.org/pairs#/polygon/pools/0x4d05f2a005e6f36633778416764e82d1d12e7fbb) on the **POLYGON NETWORK**.

```
import { FeeAmount, POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH, computePoolAddress } from '@uniswap/v3-sdk'
// ... (Other imports)
// ...
export const MATIC_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON = new Token(
  SupportedChainId.POLYGON,
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010',
  18,
  'MATIC',
  'MATIC'
)

export const CRV_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON = new Token(
  SupportedChainId.POLYGON,
  '0x172370d5cd63279efa6d502dab29171933a610af',
  18,
  'CRV',
  'CRV'
)

// Bad Address is generated: 0x458d609c135935d9Bc0733c7ED53b20E350C55B7
// Correct Address is: "0x4d05f2a005e6f36633778416764e82d1d12e7fbb"
const currentPoolAddress: string = computePoolAddress({
  factoryAddress: POOL_FACTORY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, // 0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984
  tokenA: MATIC_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON,
  tokenB: CRV_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON,
  fee: poolFee, // FeeAmount.MEDIUM, which is 3000
  initCodeHashManualOverride: POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH // 0xe34f199b19b2b4f47f68442619d555527d244f78a3297ea89325f843f87b8b54
})
```

The Pool Factory Address ("0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984") is the address specified in the [Uniswap V3 Documentation for the UniswapV3Factory Address on Polygon](https://%20%20https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments).

The initCodeHashManualOverride is set to [the default POOL_INIT_HASH_CODE from the uniswap SDK located here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk/blob/81d66099f07d1ec350767f497ef73222575fe032/src/constants.ts#L1-L5) ("**0xe34f199b19b2b4f47f68442619d555527d244f78a3297ea89325f843f87b8b54**") I have NOT changed the Uniswap SDK. The default pool init hash code should be working (FYI, I have tried with and without specifying the init hash code override. Same result).

Matic Token is indeed at address "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010" ([ref](https://app.uniswap.org/tokens/polygon/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010))

CRV Token is indeed at address "0x172370d5cd63279efa6d502dab29171933a610af" ([ref](https://app.uniswap.org/tokens/polygon/0x172370d5cd63279efa6d502dab29171933a610af))

You can [view the computeAddress source code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-sdk/blob/81d66099f07d1ec350767f497ef73222575fe032/src/utils/computePoolAddress.ts) from the Uniswap SDK. I've copied the code from the official SDK below for reference.

```
export function computePoolAddress({
  factoryAddress,
  tokenA,
  tokenB,
  fee,
  initCodeHashManualOverride
}: {
  factoryAddress: string
  tokenA: Token
  tokenB: Token
  fee: FeeAmount
  initCodeHashManualOverride?: string
}): string {
  const [token0, token1] = tokenA.sortsBefore(tokenB) ? [tokenA, tokenB] : [tokenB, tokenA] // does safety checks
  return getCreate2Address(
    factoryAddress,
    keccak256(
      ['bytes'],
      [defaultAbiCoder.encode(['address', 'address', 'uint24'], [token0.address, token1.address, fee])]
    ),
    initCodeHashManualOverride ?? POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH
  )
}
```

From what I can tell, all of the information used to calculate the Pool Address is "verified", but yet the SDK is not generating the correct pool address.

What am I doing wrong? I can provide additional information upon request. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the MATIC token address that you put in the code:

```
export const MATIC_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON = new Token(
  SupportedChainId.POLYGON,
  '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010',
```

You are putting in the base currency for the network (MATIC) whereas the [LP you are referring to](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x4d05f2a005e6f36633778416764e82d1d12e7fbb) is a Wrapped Matic ERC-20 token with the address [0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0d500b1d8e8ef31e21c99d1db9a6444d3adf1270).

Here's the fixed code based on your sample that computes the correct address: `0x4D05f2A005e6F36633778416764E82d1D12E7fbb`:

```
import { Token } from '@uniswap/sdk-core';
import { FeeAmount, POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH, computePoolAddress } from '@uniswap/v3-sdk';

const SupportedChainId = {
  POLYGON: 137,
};

const MATIC_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON = new Token(
  SupportedChainId.POLYGON,
  '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270',
  18,
  'WMATIC',
  'WMATIC'
);

const CRV_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON = new Token(
  SupportedChainId.POLYGON,
  '0x172370d5cd63279efa6d502dab29171933a610af',
  18,
  'CRV',
  'CRV'
);


const POOL_FACTORY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984';
const poolFee = FeeAmount.MEDIUM;

const currentPoolAddress = computePoolAddress({
  factoryAddress: POOL_FACTORY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  tokenA: MATIC_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON,
  tokenB: CRV_TOKEN_ON_POLYGON,
  fee: poolFee,
  initCodeHashManualOverride: POOL_INIT_CODE_HASH
});

console.log(`LP Address for WMATIC-CRV pool: ${currentPoolAddress}`);
```

The standard for LPs is to hold two ERC-20 tokens, so for the base currency (MATIC, ETH) is usually a wrapped version, which is an ERC-20.

Comment: Thank you. This had me stalled, but this information was exactly what I needed. I updated my Matic Address to the ERC-20 version, and everything worked perfectly. Your answer has been accepted. #Hero